# Chat event to deal with unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

As a follow up to [this post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/dealing-with-unanswered-questions), I think we should have an informal chat event  (or a series of chat events) to help clean up all the old, unanswered questions which we have.

Basically, we schedule a 30 min - 1 hour session, where the community comes together and discusses the unanswered questions in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table). Everyone goes through the [list of questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/unanswered) (maybe attacking different sections of the list to avoid duplication)

What we can do is identify questions of each "type" in the room:

- **Questions which *have* good answers, but the answers aren't upvoted**: These can be quickly discussed and voted on. Someone can improve existing answers or leave a better answer if necessary.
- **Questions which are easy, but just didn't get enough attention at the time**: Since there will hopefully be many of us in chat, we can see if someone can write an answer to it. Such questions can usually be answered from memory, in my experience. The answerer has the added bonus of probably getting votes from all those present in the room :) <sup>1</sup>
- **Really hard questions/Questions in niche topics**: These can be bountied. Such questions sometimes can be answered by researching them. I suggest you try it; it's a fun experience, plus you have a chance for a bounty!

(The above format is flexible, suggestions welcome!)

The session is meant to be informal, **feel free to discuss a question or anything  else in the room**. If we can work together on an answer, that's great!

### Scheduling

Let's try to schedule it so that the most people are able to come. I'm posting answers with proposed timings, feel free to add your own.

Leave a comment stating your preferences if you wish.

<sup>1. Please don't blindly vote, though</sup>

Comment: This is awesome, count me in (depending on time zones - I am in the future UTC+10)

Comment: Being in the States, the 20:00 UTC (or around there) works well for me.

Comment: I live in the future (UTC+10) and have a funny gym schedule that becomes less hilarious next week. The Tuesday 20:00UTC is fine for me from next week, as that would be 6am Wednesday morning (yes, I am awake) - but another event, if possible, could happen 20:00UTC-ish Friday (which will be early Saturday morning... But, in any case, I will be regularly hunting lost question souls and enlightening them with answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposed timing: Saturday the 8th, 8:00 UTC

Link to chat event: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3229/the-periodic-table

Comment: So, er...I won't be able to come for this one. Alternate timing?

Answer (score 1):

For a *preliminary session*, which is focused mainly on *categorizing* the questions:

Proposed timing: Thursday, Feb 27, 19:00 UTC

Comment: This one won't work for me, I'm afraid -- not that I am _absolutely_ necessary for the event to go on :). Wednesday would, though, or if this is shifted an hour ahead.

Comment: Wait, that's tomorrow. Hmm, might be a bit _too_ early.

Comment: I can make this one, I think @ManishEarth.

Comment: tschoppi, @jonsca, added a [chat event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3229/the-periodic-table?tab=schedule)

Answer (score 1):

How does 21 or 22 UTC on Thursday sound, as an alternative to the Saturday one?

Comment: I'll start earlier than that, but will probably work until 22 UTC or so.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed timing: Tuesday the 4th, next week, 20:00 UTC