# To accompany the chat event notice

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

To accompany the post [Chat event to deal with unanswered questions — details and scheduling](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342/chat-event-to-deal-with-unanswered-questions-details-and-scheduling), if people are not able to make it to the sessions (as is my case), just get into it anyway....

If you don't know the answer, research it - you'll learn something new - I just answered 7 in 24 hours, all outside my subject area expertise - learnt many great things in that time.

Get into it!